# how to send / get files via web-services in php

Tags: php, web-services, file

is this possible  ?
what is the correct way to send files ?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried, what went wrong? How do you think it should work? Do you have any code, or psuedo-code to show us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't if you want your webservice to upload/download files. Anyway you can use curl(http://fr.php.net/curl ) to upload/download file from other webserver.

To get some file uploaded to the webservice from the user it's pretty much the same as gettings it from a form, please use the superglobal variable:$_FILES ([doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)) to get upload files.

for uploading from php to a webservice

```
$fullflepath = 'C:\temp\test.jpg';
$upload_url = 'http://www.example.com/uploadtarget.php';
$params = array(
 'photo'=>"@$fullfilepath",
 'title'=>$title
);  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

the webservice to get a file

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

PS: sorry for some reason stackoverflow doesn't like to make a link of `$_FILES` ... so I have linked the superglobals page instead

Comment: did u know solution that using SOAP, webservices

Comment: for a soap service I think you have to encode the file in base64, see `base64_encode` function for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

You use this php program based on nusoap : http://biclim.com/WSClients.action

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the response of your php  service and check the file upload from iphone using this app - http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rest-client/id503860664?ls=1&mt=8
It was really helpful to debug serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here Example [Image upload](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2017/08/quick-image-upload-using-php-web.html)

```
<?php



$path="aa/";// Set your path to image upload
if(!is_dir($path)){
mkdir($path);
}
$roomPhotoList = $_POST['image'];
$random_digit=date('Y_m_d_h_i_s');
$filename=$random_digit.'.jpg';
$decoded=base64_decode($roomPhotoList);
file_put_contents($path.$filename,$decoded);

?>
```

it can be quick image upload code in php for ios and android