# Uploading image using php web service

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, web-services

I am new with php web service and trying upload an image using php web service from objective C. Actually, I have to upload an image on server and save its url in mySQL database. But I am unable to do that. Below is my code :

```
$file_name = substr ( md5(uniqid(rand(),1)), 5, 15); 
$uploaddir = 'uploading/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$newname = $file_name . $file;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newname;


$name=$_GET['username'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
$pwd=$_GET['password'];
$phone=$_GET['phone'];
$fb_user=$_GET['facebook_user'];
$fb_pwd=$_GET['facebook_pwd'];
$twitter_user=$_GET['twitter_user'];
$twitter_pwd=$_GET['twitter_pwd'];


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{

    $query="INSERT INTO `user_master` (`name`,`email`,`password`,`phone`,`facebook_user`,`facebook_pwd`,`twitter_user`,`twitter_pwd`,`followers_no`,`following_no`,`profile_view_no`,`profile_photo`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$pwd','$phone','$fb_user','$fb_pwd','$twitter_user','$twitter_pwd',0,0,0,'$uploadfile')";

    if(!mysql_query($query)) die('Error : '.mysql_error());


    $id=  mysql_insert_id();


    mysql_close();

    echo json_encode(array("response_code"=>"1","response_message"=> "Successful Transaction","UserId"=>"$id"));
}

else
{
    echo json_encode(array("response_code"=>"2","response_message"=> "Please try Again."));
      return;
}
```

The result I am getting is "Plase try again". Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Has the proper permissions your upload folder? I suspect it is there.

Comment: Yes. There was problem with permission only. Now it is solved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696542/how-to-send-get-files-via-web-services-in-php