# How to upload image using rest web services in symfony

Tags: web-services, symfony, image-uploading

I am trying upload image using rest web service in my symfony application. I have tried the following code but it is throwing the error undefined index photo. I want to know what is the right way to do it.
I have followed [how to send / get files via web-services in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696542/how-to-send-get-files-via-web-services-in-php) but it didn't worked.

Here is the my html file with which am hitting the application url:

```
<form action="http://localhost/superbApp/web/app_dev.php/upload" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST">


<input type="file" name="photo" ></br>


 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

And my controller method is like:

```
public function uploadAction(){

    $request = $this->getRequest();  /*** get the request method  ****/
    $RequestMethod = $request->getMethod();


    $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
    foreach ($_FILES["photo"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir."/".$name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony, you should use Symfony forms to do this. In your example, you put an URL which is pointing to app_dev.php, but that url doesn't work in production mode. In the Symfony cookbook there is an article explaining how upload files, which you should read:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

When you have done this, you can upload images via Rest WebService using the route specified for your action, specifying the Content-Type to multipart/form-data, and the name of the field which you add the image would be something like this package_yourbundle_yourformtype[file].